# yt-dlp how to download a specific video using timestamps, and limiting the download resolution?

Tags: python, bash, ffmpeg, yt-dlp

I am running a python program to download a video, this is the command I use:

```
command = ['powershell.exe ffmpeg',
                   '-ss', str(start),
                   '-i', '$(yt-dlp',
                   '-f', 'bestvideo[ext=webm]',

                   '-g', '"%s")' % (url_base + video_identifier),
                   '-t', str(end - start),
                   '-c:v', 'libx264', '-c:a', 'copy', '%s' % output_filename]

command = ' '.join(command)
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This prints something like
powershell.exe ffmpeg -ss 10 -i $(yt-dlp -f bestvideo[ext=webm] -g "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z15erfLqNKo") -t 10 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy C:\Users...\video.mp4

This works perfectly fine. However, I tried to download a video that had very high resolution (4K) and I want to limit the resolution when downloading. I have found that placing [height<=1080] as so should work:

powershell.exe ffmpeg -ss 10 -i $(yt-dlp -f bestvideo[ext=webm][height<=1080] -g "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z15erfLqNKo") -t 10 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy C:\Users...\video.mp4

However this does not work for me and gives me the error:
Error command "" returned non-zero exit status 1.
Output: b'The system cannot find the file specified.\r\n'

I also have noticed that only limiting the resolution does not work for me either:

powershell.exe ffmpeg -ss 10 -i $(yt-dlp -f bestvideo[height<=1080] -g "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z15erfLqNKo") -t 10 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy C:\Users...\video.mp4

Actually, placing [height<=1080] after bestvideo never works, no matter what I do.

What could be the problem? Or what command can I run to achieve both tasks (limit resolution and download specific timeframe (not whole video and cutting it)) ?

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Does it help if you enclose the `-f` parameter in double-quotes, `yt-dlp -f "bestvideo[height<=1080]" ...` ?

Comment: hello @janos , unfortunately that didnt work. I have also tried this before :(

Comment: yt-dlp has already the option `--exec`, so there's no need to build a command line in a such way.  `--exec` executes a command against the downloaded file. Do you need some guidance?

Comment: I do need some guidance, please. I am not sure where to look / where to start, I am a bit new in powershell commands. @pierpy

Comment: What is `-g` option? I did not find it in docs